# How do I get the closest DateTime from a List<DateTime>

Tags: c#, linq, list, datetime

Say I have the most recent DateTime and a List of all the possible dates. How would I efficiently go about finding the closest date time to last year's date in the list?

Say my list is comprised of the following:

```
2014-03-07
2014-03-14
2014-03-21
2014-03-28
...
2015-03-06
2015-03-13
2015-03-20
```

My most recent date is *2015-03-20*, but I want to retrieve last year's date, *2014-03-21*.

This is what I have currently, but it won't work if last year's date is one day off (eg; my time periods are stored weekly).

```
public DateTime LastYearDate()
{
    List<DateTime> times = GetAllDates();
    times.Sort();
    times.Reverse();
    DateTime currentDate = times.First();
    return times.Where(dt => dt == currentDate.AddYears(-1)).First();
}
```

I'm not sure what I would use to recursively calculate the closest date, so if you have any ideas of what direction I should take (reference to any Linq functions to check out), that would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "last year's date"? It would help if you could provide a short but complete example.

Comment: I mean a DateTime that I provide, but one year prior. I updated the question with an example.

Comment: Is the list already sorted? You could just go back 52 entries from the most recent one.

Comment: @mikez The List<DateTime> is not consistent with time periods, they can be weeks, months, quarters, years, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just order by the difference between the date in the list and the date you're looking for:

```
var dateToFind = currentDate.AddYears(-1);
times.OrderBy(t => (t - dateToFind).Duration).FirstOrDefault();
```

(The difference between two date is an instance of `TimeSpan`; the `Duration` property returns the absolute value)

Comment: Wouldn't you need to order by the absolute timespan?

Comment: This would only find the earliest date in the list not the closest.

Comment: So what would happen if the closest date to last year's is one day ahead of the date you provided? For instance, I have 3/21/2014 and 3/26/2014. My current date is 3/25/2015. This will only give me 3/21/2014, and not 3/26/2014.

Comment: @EthanDeLong order by `Math.Abs((t-dateToFind).TotalDays)` instead

Comment: @spender, good point! I fixed it, thanks. BTW, there is a simpler way than Math.Abs: the Timespan.Duration property.

Comment: @EthanDeLong, btw you might want to use First rather than FirstOrDefault, and handle the case where the list is empty separately. FirstOrDefault will return the default value of DateTime if the list is empty, which isn't very useful

Comment: In .Net Core the Duration became an extension method instead of a property.
So it will be written like:
`times.OrderBy(t => (t - dateToFind).Duration()).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 5):

As it's sorted, you can use a binary search to try to find an exact match. If [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839) returns a non-negative number, you know you've found an exact match. Otherwise, you can apply the bitwise complement operator to find the index that the value would be inserted at. You then need to check whether the value before or at that index is further from the target. So something like this:

```
var target = currentDate.AddYears(-1);
List<DateTime> times = GetAllDates();
if (times.Count == 0)
{
    // ??? Work out what you want to do here, e.g. throw an exception
}
times.Sort();
var index = times.BinarySearch(target);
if (index >= 0)
{
    return times[index];
}
int insertIndex = ~index;
// Handle boundary cases
if (insertIndex == 0)
{
    return times[0];
}
if (insertIndex == times.Count)
{
    return times[insertIndex - 1];
}
// Okay, two options - find the closest
var timeBefore = times[insertIndex - 1];
var timeAfter = times[insertIndex];
// TODO: Work out what you want to do if they're equidistant.
return target - timeBefore > timeAfter - target ? timeAfter : timeBefore;
```

Having said that, spender's comment on Thomas Levesque's answer gives a very simple solution:

```
var target = currentDate.AddYears(-1);
List<DateTime> times = GetAllDates();
if (times.Count == 0)
{
    // ??? Work out what you want to do here, e.g. throw an exception
}
return times.OrderBy(t => (target - t).Duration).First();
```

Note that [`TimeSpan.Duration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration) is always non-negative; it's like `Math.Abs` but for `TimeSpan` values.